# Array of objects in Javascript or angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am hard coding some portions of code . I have a `detailData` array that holds other objects.

```
    var detailData = [];

    detailData[0] = {
        "Detail1": null, "Detail2": null, "Detail3": null, "Detail4": null, "Detail5": null,
        "RequestTrackingId1": null, "RequestTrackingId2": null, "RequestTrackingId3": null, "RequestTrackingId4": null,
        "RequestTrackingId5": null, "header": "Request Tracking Id"
    }

    detailData[1] = {
        "Detail1": null, "Detail2": null, "Detail3": null, "Detail4": null, "Detail5": null,
        "RequestTrackingId1": null, "RequestTrackingId2": null, "RequestTrackingId3": null, "RequestTrackingId4": null,
        "RequestTrackingId5": null, "header": "Source System Code"
    }

    detailData[2] = {
        "Detail1": null, "Detail2": null, "Detail3": null, "Detail4": null, "Detail5": null,
        "RequestTrackingId1": null, "RequestTrackingId2": null, "RequestTrackingId3": null, "RequestTrackingId4": null,
        "RequestTrackingId5": null, "header": "Source System UId"
    }
```

So every detailData object will have detail1,detail2,detail3,and so on.

Now from an other array I want to assign them values like :

```
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.arc_srcsys_cds.length; i++) {
            var detailIndex = "Detail" + (i + 1);
            detailData[1].detailIndex = $scope.arc_srcsys_cds[i];
        }
```

But it is not assigning values to `detail1,detail2` and so on. Rather it is creating another field called `detailIndex`.

How can I achieve the desired result ?

Comment: `detailData[1][detailIndex] = $scope.arc_srcsys_cds[i];` You need to use square bracket notation which allows for dynamic key access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
detailData[i][detailIndex] = $scope.arc_srcsys_cds[i];
// detailData[1] will only replace or second array not for all
```

Answer (score 2):

try with:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.arc_srcsys_cds.length; i++) {
        var detailIndex = "Detail" + (i + 1);
        detailData[i][detailIndex] = $scope.arc_srcsys_cds[i];
    }
```